# Erro deploying ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, angular

Estou tentando dar deploying no meu app mais esta dando o erro da imagem, um projeto em branco consegui dar deploying, mais quando edito as telas do app acontece esse erro, ate agora não fiz nada de mais, só  mexi com o html e o css, se poderem me ajudar agradeço, não consegui encontrar nada pesquisando.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentou rodar com o comando --stacktrace para ver mais informações ?

Comment: sim, '--stacktrace' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Na verdade eu quis dizer com o parametro --stacktrace, por exemplo: `cordova build android --stacktrace --verbose`

Comment: Executei esse codigo, mais deu o mesmo erro

Comment: Quando você executa no browser ele funciona? Da uma olhada nos módulos externos que você está utilizando e veja se os mesmos estão sendo importados corretamente e se estão atualizados.

Comment: Sim funciona, esta tudo certo, tudo importado certinho